# Bind a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have a sort algorithm and I am trying to call a list but i seems only garbage variable. What is the right way?

This is what I got:

```
?- sort(list(K),Sorted).
K = Sorted, Sorted = [[_3796]]
```

This is the code:

```
list([[a,b,c,10],[e,f,g,2],[h,i,j,6]]).

sort([],[]):- !.
sort([X], [X]).
sort(list([Head|Tail]),Sorted):- %code to sort, split sort, sort and append
```

**I don't have to do this:**

```
?- sort( [ [a,b,c,10], [e,f,g,2], [h,i,j,6] ] , Sorted).
```

Comment: What do you mean by "call a list"?

Comment: Oh, are you trying to bind `K` to the nested list in the fact `list([[a,b,c,10],[e,f,g,2],[h,i,j,6]]).`?

Comment: You need to do `?- list(K), sort(K,Sorted).`, but I think you need to get rid of `list` out of your `sort` predicate. Also your `sort` predicate looks like it is sorting a flat list and not a nested list. Could you show the full code?

Comment: @Enigmativity I need to get the list in the sort. The sort works with nested list, for example: ? - sort ( [ [ a,b,c,1 ], [ d,e,f,100 ], [ l,m,n,5 ] ] , sorted)

Comment: basically i need that the person who is gonna use the code, don't have to put all the list. Just execute the algorithm with the list preloaded.

Comment: How what does a sorted nested list look like? If I had `[[4,1,2],[5,7,1],[2,7,3]]` what would my output be?

Comment: @Enigmativity It is sorted using the last element as key. Your output will be: [ [5,7,1], [4,1,2], [2,7,3] ]

Comment: @Enigmativity I edited the post, and explained a little bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way to do this would be:

```
?- list(K),sort(K,Sorted).

list([[a,b,c,10],[e,f,g,2],[h,i,j,6]]).

sort([],[]):- !.
sort([X], [X]).
sort([Head|Tail],Sorted):- %code to sort, split sort, sort and append
```

You could call it the way that you were doing it, but you'd have to do this messy approach:

```
sort(list([Head|Tail]),Sorted):- list([Head|Tail]), %code to sort, split sort, sort and append
```